# json encode displaying "null" on body

Tags: php, android, json

My code is shown below, I can display the body text well if I echo it, but when I try encoding it, it returns null

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","eservices"); 
    $sql="select * from news order by id DESC";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
    $news=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($news, array("headline"=>$row[2],"body"=>$row[3]));
    }
    echo json_encode(array("news_response"=>$news));
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: i have been trying for days to encode this text, but it still returns null.

Comment: To start with, move the `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` to be under the connection, its to late doing it after a query has been run

Comment: Please show an example of what is in the array, before you `json_encode` it, by adding a `print_r($news);` and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36693642/edit) you question adding the output

Comment: Can we assume by your silence that moving the charset command has fixed this??

Comment: sorry for late response, it worked, i moved my charset statement to just below the connection.

thank you so much guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shoudl move the `mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");` to be under the connection, its to late doing it after a query has been run

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","eservices");
 mysqli_set_charset($con,"utf8");
```